# How to avoid autogenerated values check on id with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE `chat_session` (
 `session_id` BINARY(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Chat session identifier',
 ...
 PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
```

and the following class:

```
@ToString()
@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat_session")
public class ChatSession {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "session_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String sessionId;
```

which, when saving, turns into an error like the following:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
```

actually, I don't want to change the schema, and I need to feed my entities with proper values, not autogenerated. Can I do it?

Comment: Remove the `@GeneratedValue` and when you create the object, assign a value. It will work.

Comment: when use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  declare session_id as int and add identity in db

Comment: I can't change the schema, it's a string

Comment: @aksappy actually not, if I remove it I get the following error: `18:53:57 [main] ERROR TableStructure - could not read a hi value
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '****NAME HERE****.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) `

Comment: session_id is a UUI?

Comment: I thought as @aksappy, Is table chat_session's session_id column a primary key? Can we see if there is a constraints for it?

Comment: Yes there is a constraint declared for it: `PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)` I've updated the question with that

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the database schema , you have to manually generate an unique ID and assign it for the new entities.

You can do it by simply removing `@GeneratedValue` :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat_session")
public class ChatSession {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "session_id")
    private String sessionId;
}
```

Consult with the business requirement to see if there are any rules about the ID format. If yes , implement it and manually generate a new ID and set it for the new entity by yourself. If you do not have such business rule , you can simply use the UUID generator from Java to ensure the generated ID is unique:

```java
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Comment: the point is that I'm assigning it already, but I get the same error. If I remove the `generatedValue` annotation, then I get another error like ` com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '**table-name***.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist`

Comment: Does `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false` help you at that situation?